# He forgot Yaaleh VeYavo in early maariv on Rosh Chodesh. Does he repeat the Amidah?

Tags: tefilla, rosh-chodesh-new-month

[Halachipedia](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Yaaleh_VeYavo#Rosh_Chodesh) says

> If one forgets Yaaleh VeYavo at Mariv/Arvit once one finished the
>   Bracha of Retzeh (and all the more so if one finished Shmoneh Esrei)
>   one doesn’t return to the Bracha or repeat Shmoneh Esrei. The same is
>   true whether it is the first or second day of Rosh Chodesh.

I always understood the reason to be that Rosh Chodesh was not proclaimed at night.

It is possible to daven Maariv after Plag Hamincha see [here for example](http://rabbikaganoff.com/is-it-time-for-maariv/) . The opinion that one can  daven Maariv then holds that after  Plag Hamincha it is night. But practically it is before sunset.

So my question is if someone left out  Yaaleh VeYavo at Maariv (after Plag Hamincha Erev Rosh Chodesh and before sunset or even night) would he have to repeat the Amidah?

Comment: I'm missing something. Why would he? If he forgot even on R"Ch itself we don't make him repeat it, so kal vechomer where it wasn't even R"Ch.

Comment: Who says Yaaleh veYavo even should be said then at all? It's not Rosh Chodesh yet.

Answer (score 1):

Inasmuch as it was the zman maariv, he fulfilled his obligation (since they would not have consecrated the new moon yet then) and therefore would not repeat.

Comment: Agreed. He's _made it night_ - so he's got the Halachot of night. But I'd love to see a source. If Bet Din them made it Rosh Chodesh (late afternoon) then he wouldn't need to say it that evening anyways.

Comment: They might have https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/94299/759

Answer (score 0):

One does not repeat the shemona esray at maariv for omitting yaale v'yavo. This is the same on the first and second night of rosh chodesh. One does repeat if omitted during shachris or mincha. This is in the artscholl sidur in the back where it lists selected laws concerning prayers and sourced there from orech chaim 422:1

Comment: This doesn't address Maariv before Shkiya at all...